# Adding realtime database to my app in android studio - Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0

Tags: android

I've been working with firebase to access my app...its working fine but my problem   with when i connect to Realtime database in android studio shows following error.
Please help me out of this error.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOtrR.png)

Comment: remove this and then sync it will work fine. :15.0.0

Comment: i need to add the realtime database dependency...this line of code will adding automatically (compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0' ) when i'm going to add dependencies

Comment: well this line will also do the same. Actually I think it's a bug in AS that goes like this. otherwise the version is only 16.0.1

Comment: uh bro! i was stuck since last week ... really i don't know what to do for this...please let me know if you have any idea on about that plss....

Comment: Have you tried what I have wrote in my answer ?

Comment: Yeah i tried also it's shows successfully synchronized...but again it will ask "Add the Realtime Database" in assistant.

Comment: you really need to understand how android studio works. :) after successful sync you then start working on your classes for realtime database. Assistant won't update itself because you added the library manually.

Comment: Okay. i'll do as well you said. Thank you for your time bro!

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove this `(:15.0.0)` from your compile command, so this line should actually look like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

**Instead of this:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```